# Electric field inside a cylinder containing a grounded wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Say we have a hollow cylinder at 100V.

I understand that if this cylinder were empty, you would have no electric field inside because if you drew a Gaussian surface, it would contain no charge.

However, say you put a wire inside the cylinder (at the centre) but you grounded the wire. I assume that grounding means the wire would be at 0V so this would set up a field gradient thus meaning there's a field inside the cylinder.

But doesn't the act of grounding remove the charge from the inner wire, thus meaning there's no charge inside your Gaussian surface so no field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a conductor is grounded does not mean there cannot be charge on the conductor. See figure below.

The metal cylinder is +100 Volts with respect to ground. In order to have a voltage between the cylinder and ground, there needs to be an electric field between.

The wire in the center is connected to ground. It is at the same potential, thus it like the ground is negatively charged.

Thus an electric field exists between the wire and the cylinder.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ground wire is tricky is this case because the wire part in the cylinder does get electrons attracted to it (assuming a positive cylinder).  Similar to a capacitor.

Comment: So this means there is an electric field?

Comment: Yes because now you van make a Gaussian shape inside the cylinder but around the wire that contains the attracted charge.